# The very last piece of code at the bottom is darkened

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a game about dodging falling blocks. Sounds really simple, but I'm just starting with Python and Pygame. Anyways, I was trying to define a function(Enemy) inside of another function(Player). Player acts as my main function. When I try to define a variable outside of the Player, my display window where the game runs doesn't open. I thought, "Oh I just need to make it inside of the function so I can call it." I started to try that, but Enemy code is darkened.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import time
from pygame import mixer

Red = (255, 138, 138)
White = (255, 255, 255)
Green = (138, 255, 169)
Blue = (154, 138, 255)
Peach = (255, 204, 138)
Purgenta = (247, 138, 255)
Draw = pygame.draw.rect
playerx = 0
blocky = 0
velocityx = 0
accelerationx = 0
velocityy = 0
accelerationy = 0.0001
blockx = random.randint(0, 350)
#blockx = 10
wait = time.sleep
i = 7
j = 2
gameRunning = True
spawnblock = 0

#while gameRunning == True:
    #print('hello')

def player():
    pygame.init()

    DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((500,400),0,32)

    DISPLAY.fill(White)

    mixer.music.load('Background music 1.mp3')
    mixer.music.play(-1)

    global blocky
    global velocityx
    global playerx
    global blockx
    global velocityy
    global blocky
    global spawnblock
    global accelerationy

    if blocky == 350:
            print('AAAA')

    while True:
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:


                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        DISPLAY.fill((255, 255, 255))
        Draw(DISPLAY, Blue, (playerx, 350, 50, 50))
        Draw(DISPLAY, Red, (blockx, blocky, 50, 50))
        playerx += velocityx
        velocityx *= accelerationx
        
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            velocityx = 1
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            velocityx = -1
        pygame.display.update()

    def enemy():
        print('hi')
```

Comment: Because `while True` does not have a `break` anywhere in it so the code at the bottom will never reach. Remove a tab (or 4 spaces) from `def enemy()` and the line after it.

Comment: Where do you call the `player()` function? `player` is  a function. It is not executed until it is called.

Comment: you don't call `enemy()` anywhere, so the enemy never greets you. this is akin to strolling down a forested path, but not having any bandits ambush your group on the way to your destination. i.e., the enemy will never "see" you so will never know to drop by to say hello and interact with you.

Comment: Remember that you only need a `global` statement if you are assigning a new value to the variable.  In your case, `playerx` and `velocityx` are the only two variables that require `global` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should call out the player function, cause this is where the entire game runs, so at the end of your code add `player()`
what `player()` does is that it runs the function, when you create a function, you store values or stuff inside it, but the function doesnt run itself, you have to define it by putting it's name and with brackets.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import time
from pygame import mixer

Red = (255, 138, 138)
White = (255, 255, 255)
Green = (138, 255, 169)
Blue = (154, 138, 255)
Peach = (255, 204, 138)
Purgenta = (247, 138, 255)
Draw = pygame.draw.rect
playerx = 0
blocky = 0
velocityx = 0
accelerationx = 0
velocityy = 0
accelerationy = 0.0001
blockx = random.randint(0, 350)
#blockx = 10
wait = time.sleep
i = 7
j = 2
gameRunning = True
spawnblock = 0

#while gameRunning == True:
    #print('hello')

def player():
    pygame.init()

    DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((500,400),0,32)

    DISPLAY.fill(White)

    mixer.music.load('Background music 1.mp3')
    mixer.music.play(-1)

    global blocky
    global velocityx
    global playerx
    global blockx
    global velocityy
    global blocky
    global spawnblock
    global accelerationy

    if blocky == 350:
            print('AAAA')

    while True:
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:


                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        DISPLAY.fill((255, 255, 255))
        Draw(DISPLAY, Blue, (playerx, 350, 50, 50))
        Draw(DISPLAY, Red, (blockx, blocky, 50, 50))
        playerx += velocityx
        velocityx *= accelerationx
      if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            velocityx = 1
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            velocityx = -1
        pygame.display.update()

    def enemy():
        print('hi')
player()
```

And the only reason the enemy code is darkened is because it is after the while loop, so define the enemy function before initialising the while loop, and in my oppinion instead of doing all of that, put the enemy function outside of the player function, cause i dont understand your point in putting it in the player function, the enemy function will still run the same even if it isn't inside the player function, but as long as you call `enemy()` that is when that function runs.